# Angular Firebase doesn't work when projectId is sent as environment variable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, webpack, angularfire2

This is my case, I've set up angular firebase in my project, this project is supposed to deploy in several environments so I set up webpack to pass environment variables to environment.prod.ts file, so I don't need to do any change in the code when deploying in one environment or another

This is how my environment.prod.ts file looks like:

```js
export const environment = {
  // other variables
  firebase: {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASEURL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID,
    measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID
  }
};
```

my inferface for environment variables looks like:

```js
declare var process: Process;

interface Process {
  env: Env
}

interface Env {
  FIREBASE_APIKEY: string,
  FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN: string,
  FIREBASE_DATABASEURL: string,
  FIREBASE_PROJECTID: string,
  FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET: string,
  FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID: string,
  FIREBASE_APPID: string,
  FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID: string
}

interface GlobalEnvironment {
  process: Process
}
```

and importing in my app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ]
  // ...
})
```

but for some reason, when I do this, **the projectId variable is not recognized once my app is deployed** and rise this error in the console

```
main.973a03e40daff299cb0a.js:1 ERROR FirebaseError: projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options
    at new e (http://192.168.43.214:8876/main.973a03e40daff299cb0a.js:1:49175)
    at Function.t.YT (http://192.168.43.214:8876/main.973a03e40daff299cb0a.js:1:267849)
```

But when I set the projectId (its value) directly in the environment file as string everything works well, I tried concatenating with a string or recasting firebase object once app.module.ts loads, and log in the browser console values, and everything is there, but still is triggering that error, and I don't now why.

I'll really appreciate your help.
(sorry for my bad English)